# error displaying core-ajax custom element

Tags: polymer

i am making a custom element to display a wall of album covers from a subsonic server. when declared the element will query the server and get back 200 response. the response logs in the console correctly. but nothing is rendered in the browser.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="album-info-big-art.html">
<polymer-element name="albums-wall" attributes="url">
<template>
 <core-ajax auto url="{{url}}" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
  <template id='albums' repeat="{{response.subsonic-response.albumList2.album}}">
   <album-info-big-art artist='{{artist}}' title='{{name}}' img='{{coverArt}}'></album-info-big-art>
  </template>
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer('albums-wall',{
   responseChanged: function(e) {
     var albums = this.response;
     console.log(albums);
   }
 });   
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

the response looks like.

```
Object {subsonic-response: Object}
 subsonic-response: Object
  albumList2: Object
   album: Array[60]
__proto__: Object
status: "ok"
version: "1.10.2"
xmlns: "http://subsonic.org/restapi"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

i am pretty sure i have missed something in the js section.

Comment: I tried your code with a call to the Github API to list my repositories. It worked fine. Are you sure that your URL is correct? Maybe you need some kind of authentication? Is the request sent to the server? Did you get no response back or did you get a 200 response, but nothing is displayed in the browser? Are there any errors logged in the browser development console?

Comment: the url is correct. and the response returns data as expected. no errors in console either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the property name *subsonic-response*. You cannot use a dash in a path property name. Rewrite your expression to use array syntax: `response['subsonic-response']...`.